# JavaScript fadeIn custom times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering the best way to code HTML list-items to appear one after another using delays after a setTime. So, essentially; Show first li, then second li, pause for 3000 show last li. Something like this, where I can easily toggle the times for each.

```
<li class="final_1">
```

Does something like this seem close and a good approach?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    final_1.delay(5000).fadeIn()}$
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a simple loop :

```
$('.final_1').each(function(i,ele) {
    $(ele).delay(i*3000).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wApnY/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery, this should work....

```
var timers = [5000, 5000, 5000, 3000]; //allows setting of specific times for each 

$(".final_1").each(function(index){
   $(this).delay(index * timers[index]).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to yours, I have crossed a task using delayed `toggle()` in `jQuery`.

```
$(".final_1").each(function(i, e) {
     $(this).delay(i).toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 2000);
    });
```

Also I am having an demo in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsx4v/1/)

**EDIT:** With reference to ***adeneo's answer***, check for the `last-child` in `li` and increase the timer.

```
$('.final_1').each(function(i,ele) {
    var dt = 1000;
    if($(this).is(':last-child')) // To check the last child in li
        dt = 2000;                // and increase the timer
    $(ele).delay(i*dt).fadeIn('slow');    
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dGDJC/)